# iScroll4 swipe down and up events

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-mobile, iscroll4

I've written my code as below but when I scroll always `onScrollEnd` gets fired. How to detect whether user is scrolling down or scrolling up ??

```
myScroll = new iScroll('SaleListingContainer', { desktopCompatibility: true, useTransition: true,
                        // topOffset: pullDownOffset,
                        onRefresh: function() {
                            alert("refresh");
                        },
                        onScrollMove: function() {
                            alert("move");
                        },
                        onScrollEnd: function() {
                            alert("end");
                        } 
                    });
```

Thanks for your time and help in advance. Thanks alot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `dirY` attribute, which is 1 if the user scrolls down or -1 if the user scrolls up:

```
onScrollEnd: function() {
            if (this.dirY == 1) { alert('scrolling down'); }
            else if (this.dirY == -1) { alert('scrolling up'); }
}
```